# How to refresh label after changing color in wicket

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

I use Wicket 1.5

When i change color it is really changed on the page only after refreshing using F5. How to refresh it in backend?

I use this lines for changing color:
dateDescription.add(AttributeModifier.replace("style", "color:red;"));
add(dateDescription);

UPDATE #1
Now i use AJAX but still have to refresh page for changing color. Could you tell me what i did wrong?

```
    // in page class
    public class FilterUpdateBehavior extends AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior {
        public FilterUpdateBehavior(String event) {
            super(event);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            RefreshResult result = getResult(target);
            if (result.getStatus() == RefreshResultStatus.DATE_NOT_SET) {
                dateIntervalFilterPanel.setAlarmDateStatus(true);
            } else {
                dateIntervalFilterPanel.setAlarmDateStatus(false);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    // in date panel class
    dateDescription.add(new AttributeModifier("style", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public String getObject() {
                    String cssClass = null;
                    if (isAlarmDateStatus()) {
                        cssClass = "color:red;";
                    } else {
                        cssClass = "color:black;";
                    }
                    return cssClass;
                }
            }));
    add(dateDescription);
```

UPDATE #2

```
    public RefreshResult getResults(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        // ... somewhere here additional logic of getting particulate RefreshResult
        target.add(table);
        target.add(paging);
        target.add(loadingPanel);
        return new RefreshResult(resultType);
    }
```

UPDATE #3 FINAL (IT HELPED ME)
I miss this code line when i change isAlarmDateStatus, now it works fine. Thanks to Andrea!

```
    target.add(dateDescription);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code line looks right but you must use AJAX to reflect your changes without reloading the entire page. Unfortunately Wicket 1.5 is really outdated and there are few resources online to provide you an example of AJAX support. You might try to look into the old 1.5 AJAX examples code here:

https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/build/wicket-1.5.17/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/ajax/builtin

Comment: i changed implementation with AJAX and updated question, could you tell my your opinion?

Comment: I guess you missed the code of getResult(...). I expect to see 'target.addComponent' somewhere in your code.

Comment: i added getResults(..) method, i have target.add for 3 elements of page - filter, paging, loadingPanel. And these elements are really updated after onUpdate event. Should i use "target.add(dateIntervalFilterPanel)" for updating panel with the label i wanted to update it during onUpdate event?

Comment: You should be ok by just adding the label to 'AjaxRequestTarget target'. Have you called setOutputMarkupId​ on every component you want to update via AJAX?